# Quadrotor flight controller and actuator dynamics

Tags: control, brushless-dc-motor, quad-copter

Do off the shelf flight controllers for quadrotors, such as pixhawk or cc3d, take into account BLDC actuator dynamics? For example you can design a controller to compute propeller rates, and then assume the propellers instantly achieve those rates, or you can build the actuator dynamics into a model and account for the difference between actual and desired propeller rates in closed loop control.

I previously assumed the former was true, and I am building my flight controller with this assumption (the motors achieve the computed rates instantaneously) but am running into problems with attitude stability. I am beginning to suspect might be because of the assumption about the motors, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: fyi: There is an [Area51 proposal for a specialized Drones stack](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95767/drones).

Comment: interesting, I can't post this question there though, I need 5 reputation :/

Comment: Questions asking what a products are capable of are not great for a Stack Exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's better to ask for help with solving your specific problem. For instance, it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see.

Comment: I believe this is a practical answerable question based on a problem I am having - that is quadrotor attitude control. It is not so much about what a product is capable of rather, whether it does or doesn't do this one thing. Knowing this would help me to proceed in getting my own controller to work.

Comment: That's why I suggested you "include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see". While Chucks general answer is excellent, a more specific question could elicit a more specific answer and solve your actual problem, rather than skirting around the edges of it.

Comment: Its better to posit the question from a design prospective, questions that are not specific and vague make it harder for people to answer and generate many answers and noise. Please ask specific questions. See: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To answer your question: A BLDC motor controller has to either estimate or have some kind of model of the motor, especially the motor load curve. There are several parameters that can model a BLDC motor and there are books just focusing on control of these motors. It would be difficult to know exactly what kind of BLDC control scheme an off the shelf controller would use without looking at the code and schematics.

Answer (score 1):

All of the papers I've read on flight controllers (disclaimer: I haven't tried to implement one) appear to use a similar method for control - a PID controller wrapped around each axis of control, where the outputs are distributed and summed as motor pairs. Each motor's control signal is a sum of those PID outputs, with the sign of the output varying by motor position.

So, if that's the case, then no, there is no dynamic accounted for in the flight controller. The flight controller sends the reference to the PID controller, **which needs to be tuned**. This is one of the drawbacks of PID control - you need to tune it. Tuning can be a very time consuming process.

Fortunately, there are [procedures written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziegler%E2%80%93Nichols_method) to tune PID controllers, but just because a method exists doesn't mean it's easy to do.

There seems to be an [auto-tune feature](http://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/ac_rollpitchtuning.html) for some flight controllers, but again, the tuning needs to happen *because the thrust dynamics are not taken into account*.

One motor with a large prop and the same motor with a small prop are going to produce different amounts of thrust at different speeds. That is, *even if you know the BLDC motor dynamics*, the thrust you get from that motor (which is really what you care about), still isn't accounted for because you haven't modeled the effects of the prop.

Tuning the PID gains is how this variation is taken into account. The gains are larger or smaller, as needed, to account for response time in the motor/prop combination.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. It seems like PID controllers are rather robust to these of variations assuming the gains can be tuned appropriately. I am implementing a nonlinear controller, which is similar to a PID in the sense that it has proportional angular rate and Euler angle gains, which are sort of like the derivative and proportional angle gains in a PID. These are what I have been playing around with and trying to tune for a while, but I cannot achieve a very stable hover.